# Why reload is invisible with ajax but is visible from console?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So, I have a pretty old project which I made when I was much less experienced (hence the approach must be very terrible) than now and now looking into my old code I got some questions about mechanisms behind.

I have `index.php` and `input.php`, when I press submit on the form on `index.php` the data from the form is sent to `input.php` and then data is validated, put into MySQL database. If everything was alright by that moment server just returns as response:

```html
<script>location.reload();</script>
```

Here is how I send that request:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: $("#input_form").attr("action"),
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(info){$("body").html(info);}
});
```

So, basically, the page is forced to be reloaded if everything went alright. It works, we can see new data on the page.

Questions are:

1) Why page reload is literally invisible? What mechanism is behind? As far as I get the whole body's html changes to script tag with reload function inside hence it should be similar (if not the same) to putting `$('body').html("<script>location.reload()</script>")` in the browser console yet the difference is visible very good - if I put that in the browser console then refresh button changes, icon of the currently active browser tab also changes to reload icon which does not happen with the request

2) Why Chrome dev tools sees that reload as redirect from `input.php` (Network tab) and puts as response the whole html index.php generates which doesn't happen if I run `$('body').html("<script>location.reload()</script>")` in the console?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can agree that a `location.reload();` simply reloads the whole page. It could just as well be a completely different page.

The `$("body").html(info);` replaces the content of the `<body> ... </body>` element of the page completely, but that is not the whole page. A HTML page is more. It's got headers, a `<head>`, scripts, and more. This all stays put when you use `$("body").html(info);`.

The [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html) says that `.html()` uses the browser's [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property. The exact mechanism is:

1. The specified value is parsed as HTML resulting in a [DocumentFragment object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) representing the new set of DOM nodes for the new elements.
2. The element's contents are replaced with the nodes in the new [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). Because all of the nodes are inserted into the document at once, **only one reflow and render is triggered** instead of potentially one for each node inserted if they were inserted separately.

The page `reload()` does a complete rebuild of the document, including everything. It builds a DOM notes tree, and while it does that tries to render it. It might be that **several reflows and renderings are triggered** when building a whole page. For instance when a CSS file is loaded, or when more HTML source comes in. Many pages also have Javascript that modify the page slightly after loading. That's what you see when a complete reload is done.

Comment: Sorry, I think you didn't clearly get what I wanted to know. I still would like to know why one actions differ so much under request from another when they clearly do the same thing. Effect is the same - we see new data on the reloaded page but in one case I don't even see this reload and in the second case (from the console) I clearly see page being reloaded

Comment: I think I got perfectly what you wanted to know, and I explained it. Whether I explained it in such a way that you are able to understand it is a whole other matter. I might have fallen short there. But it might also be that you won't be happy until someone points out, and explains, all the difference in the source code of the browser, before you accept the fact that these are two quite different methods of reloading content. I'll add a bit more to make it more explicit.

Comment: Ok, I see what you added. The thing is in both cases I run `location.reload()` just one is returned from the server from ajax request and the second one is just run from console `$('body').html("<script>location.reload()</script>")`. In the end they both go through `$('body').html()` function resulting running `location.reload()`. I don't get the whole page's html from the server I get only `<script>location.reload()</script>`

Comment: Ah, I see, what you mean. I didn't get that when I first read your question. It is highly unusual to reload a page like that, but if it works, it's fine. What `$('body').html("<script>location.reload()</script>");` does is first replace the whole body with the script, basically clearing the page, and then it reloads the page. That's what you see when you execute it from the console. You're not seeing that when using the AJAX call. If you are using the Chrome developer tools (F12) you can follow what happens in the performance tab. Look at the timings and see if you can spot the differences.

Comment: well, this is weird, I tried to see what is happening in the performance tab and it seems in the case with console it spends time to parse HTML but with AJAX request it doesn't

Comment: Well, I think that's probably as good as an explanation you will get. Browsers are very complex pieces of software.

Comment: Just thought there might be more to that, maybe some jquery ajax mechanism which stops browser from actual refreshing the page even if we put script tag with refresh command in it... but if there really isn't any then I guess it is rather impossible to find out what really happens. It is not like something worth deep research as well because this approach is pretty bad and no one is recommended to do this way

Answer (score 0):

location.reload() means reload the current page,when you are getting response from server,
You don't need to write html script to reload the page, try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: $("#input_form").attr("action"),
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(info){
     if(info) {
      location.reload();
   }
}
});
```

Comment: With this code I see reload happening which ruins ajax idea of changing the data on the page without actually reloading it. What is weird and what I'm trying to get is why I don't see this effect when I get `<script>location.reload()</script>` as response and then put it on the page, I see new data but without actually seeing any page reloads

Comment: @DarkZ, after reading your English i thought that i am not good at English, can you make as   simple as simple so i can understand easily

Comment: I..I think I can't put it simplier... is my English really this bad?